# how to start a project using htmlpy with flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have read the documentation, but i do not comprend how to traduce [the example shown](http://htmlpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials.html#integration-with-django) into some flask code... or more explicitely I don't know how to start.

## --EDIT--

From what I understand, I need to bind the back-end (flask) with htmlpy. It is more how to add the GUI with htmlpy and make it interact with flask that puzzle me.

Comment: @tim I know that already, just cannot do it with Flask, that is why I asked for some help. Do you have an idea on how to start?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know, Maybe you should leave it, for htmlpy has a long time without update.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but this is my try.

> Django can be used for standalone application development using
>   htmlPy. The integration can be done easily. In the previous section,
>   the django application and projects can be kept in back_end_codes
>   directory. In the GUI driver file, include this code before
>   initializing GUI for loading django settings.

With this doc [Tutorials for common tasks](https://htmlpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials.html) and this [example in github](https://github.com/amol-mandhane/htmlPy)

### backend

```
import htmlPy


class BackEnd(htmlPy.Object):

    def __init__(self, app):
        super(BackEnd, self).__init__()
        self.app = app

    @htmlPy.Slot()
    def say_hello_world(self):
        self.app.html = u"Hello, world"
```

*I think we should add flask routes like*

````
import htmlPy
from Flask import *


class BackEnd(htmlPy.Object):
    @htmlPy.Slot()
    def say_hello_world(self):
        self.app.html = u"Hello, world"
    @htmlPy.Slot()
    #@app.route('/page1')
    def page1(self):
        return '''<h1>page1</h1>```
````

and in front end:

```
<html>
  <body>
<a
href="BackEnd.spage1"
data-bind="true">
  Click to show page1
</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am not sure. I think it will work.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Be back with a comment on it